# Windows simple volume migration

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I converted a portion of my HDD to a simple volume on Windows and now I cannot mount it on Linux. I'd like to migrate my files from that simple volume to my Ubuntu machine. I know there is data on it, but I can't read it on Windows.

How would I go about this?

Comment: "now I cannot mount it on Linux" Why not? Without specifics we can't help; any error notices during manual mounting? "but I can't read it on Windows." You meant Linux? Otherwise you need to ask that on a Windows related forum.

Comment: @Rinzwind I had two paritions on my drive, simple volume which had all data and another volume which has my Linux. Before that, I could mount it(the data) because it was NTFS. Now that I changed it to a simple volume, it doesn't show in Ubuntu.

Comment: "simple volume" is a microsoft thing? Then there are 2 things: just as with NTFS you are likely to need a driver to support "simple volume" and if that is not possible "simple volume" is not supported in Linux... can you switch back to NTFS?

Comment: If I switch back to NTFS, that would require a format of the drive, which I am not prepared to do, because the data is still stuck there.